# "How is it to live in England" vs "How is to live in England"

Tags: questions, infinitives

> 1. How is it to live in England?
> 2. How is it living in England?

vs

> 3. How is to live in England?
> 4. How is living in England?

To my non native ear, the first and the second statements are right, the other ones are wrong. Am I right? what grammar rule should I apply?

Comment: More native like, is: What's it like living in England. What's it like to live in England.

Comment: You **do not use how** to ask for a description of a thing or place. For example, if you say _How is Birmingham?_, you are not asking someone what kind of place Birmingham is; you are asking them if they are enjoying living or working there. If you want them to give you a description of Birmingham, you say _What is Birmingham like?_ ▲ What is Fiji like?
You **do not say** _How do you think of Birmingham?_ You say _What do you think of Birmingham?_ ▲ What do you think of the photo on the front of The Student? ▲ What did you think of Holland?

Comment: @Mvlog  **How's** the weather where you are?   It's hot and dry and mostly on fire out here in California right now.

Comment: @MvLog - I agree with Andrew.  I see nothing unusual in asking "How's New York?"

Comment: @Andrew It's been answered in my comment in the example about Burmingham.

Comment: @MvLog  No, my question doesn't ask if you are *enjoying* the weather.  It asks you to *describe* the weather, Q: "How's the weather there?" A: "It's cold and rainy almost every day."

Comment: @Andrew In effect, it does. Compare: _What was the weather like on your vacation?_

Comment: I can't understand why sentence #3 is wrong. I've always thought that infinitives and gerunds were interchangeable when used as subjects! Hence, if #4 is right, then #3 should be right too.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out in the comments, if your intention is to ask for a description of England and daily life there, then you would instead ask:

> **What is it like** living in England?

Your question is fine if instead you want to know how someone is *doing* while they are living in England.  For example, suppose my friend is staying in London for the summer, and I text her to see how she's doing:

> Me: How **is it living** in England?
>   She: It's tough.  I can't understand half the accents.  You'd almost think they weren't speaking English at all.

"How is living in England" is also fine, and means much the same thing as "How is *it* living in England".  The "it" here is the ["existential dummy pronoun"](http://www.brighthubeducation.com/english-homework-help/60131-existential-there-and-dummy-it-pronouns/), which has no real meaning of its own.

Your first sentence is not as idiomatic, although it seems OK with a comma:

> How **is it, to live** in England?

Your sentence #3 is not correct.